# App crashes : W/Ads: It is not recommended to show an interstitial when app is not in foreground

Tags: android, interstitial

If user is fast and closes activity before the interstitial ad appears app crashes:

```
08-10 16:55:25.254 17484-17484/com.myapp
W/Ads: It is not recommended to show an interstitial when app is not 
in foreground.
08-10 15:44:58.470 14219-14219/com.myapp W/google-breakpad: ### ### 
### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
08-10 15:44:58.470 14219-14219/com.myapp W/google-breakpad: Chrome 
build fingerprint:
08-10 15:44:58.470 14219-14219/com.myapp W/google-breakpad: 1.1
08-10 15:44:58.470 14219-14219/com.myapp W/google-breakpad: 2
08-10 15:44:58.470 14219-14219/com.myapp W/google-breakpad: 
45012863-7d3b-4c30-8ccf-e65394c57d85
08-10 15:44:58.470 14219-14219/com.myapp W/google-breakpad: ### ### 
### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
08-10 15:44:58.471 14219-14219/com.myapp A/libc: Fatal signal 11 
(SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x4 in tid 14219 (t.myapp)
```

There are two activities. `interstitialAd.show();` is in `onCreate` of first.

```
    final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true)
            .build();

    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-6546546546546546~6546544");
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-333333333333333/1111111");
    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            interstitialAd.show();
            }
        });
```

First activity usually takes 2-3 seconds of user, so user clicks button  and ad appears on the second activity.

```
    View.OnClickListener button = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //My code

            final Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            toHeads.putExtra("ids", mId);
            startActivity(intent);
            FirstActivity.this.finish();
        }
    };
```

But when `SecondActivity` also ends quickly   (with `SecondActivity.this.finishAndRemoveTask();`)  app crashes. 
I think i need somehow to stop interstitial ad before ending `SecondActivity` but there isn't any function like `interstitialAd.stopLoading()` or something.